# <mx:Style/> equivalent in ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, coding-style

I am looking for something equivalent to the "mx:Style" tag in Flex for actionscript 3. Currently I am loading the skin using StyleManager.loadStyleDeclaration().

But this loads the skin at runtime which is not my intention.
Thus am looking for something similar to "mx:Style" tag in as3 such that it embeds the skin and is not required to load at runtime.

Many thanks for any replies.

Ashish.

Answer (score 0):

[From here](http://drawlogic.com/2007/06/01/loading-external-css-stylesheets-in-flash9-as3-cs3/)

```
package
{
 import flash.display.Sprite;
 import flash.events.Event;
 import flash.net.URLLoader;
 import flash.net.URLRequest;
 import flash.text.StyleSheet;
 import flash.text.TextField;
 import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;

 public class CSSFormattingExample extends Sprite
 {
  var loader:URLLoader;
  var field:TextField;
  var exampleText:String = "<h1>This is a headline</h1>
    " + "This is a line of text. <span class=\"bluetext\">" +
    "This line of text is colored blue.</span>";

  public function CSSFormattingExample():void
  {
   field = new TextField();
   field.width = 300;
   field.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
   field.wordWrap = true;
   addChild(field);

   var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("example.css");

   loader = new URLLoader();
   loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCSSFileLoaded);
   loader.load(req);
  }

  public function onCSSFileLoaded(event:Event):void
  {
   var sheet:StyleSheet = new StyleSheet();
   sheet.parseCSS(loader.data);
   field.styleSheet = sheet;
   field.htmlText = exampleText;
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the same without Loader and EventListener, you have this [way very easy](http://blog.swfjunkie.com/2009/10/embedding-css-flex/) :

```
// Embed your stylesheet with the octet-stream mime-type
[Embed(source="assets/stylesheet.css", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
private var stylesCSS:Class;

public function createStyleSheetObject():StyleSheet
{
    // create a new StyleSheet instance
    var styleSheet:StyleSheet = new StyleSheet();
    // create a instance of the styles as ByteArray
    var byteArray:ByteArray = new stylesCSS() as ByteArray;
    // read the content
    var stylesString:String = byteArray.readUTFBytes(byteArray.length);
    // parse the string by the stylesheet and done!
    styleSheet.parseCSS(stylesString);
    return styleSheet;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I was looking for this myself and just now found the answer.

```
<fx:Style source="path/to/sheet.css"/>
```

Yup, it's exactly the same, except now it's in the `fx` namespace.

Comment: he's looking for a way in ACTIONSCRIPT